# How to write the CAMLquery for column name:ID

Tags: query

**Column name:**   CauseID:Code
**The type of information in this column is:**      Lookup

```
function searchFunction()
{
    var strDamcode = $('#searchDamage').val().trim();
    if ($('#wrap header').find('#loadingIconDiv').length == 0){
        pageLoader();
        //if($("#strDamcode").val()!=" ")
        if(strDamcode != '')
        {
            //var damageCodeID = $("#strDamcode").val();
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("WorkOrderDamage");
            var camlQuery1 = new SP.CamlQuery();

            **camlQuery1.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CauseID_x003a_Code' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>"+strDamcode+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");**
            this.collListItems1 = oList1.getItems(camlQuery1);
            clientContext.load(collListItems1);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSearchSucceed), Function.createDelegate(this, this.searchFunctionMain));
        }
        else{
            searchFunctionMain();
        }
        searchClicked = true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code what I understand is you want to write query for such item whose column value matches the text entered in Textbox. So based on the my understanding your query should be like this

1. If you want exact match

   ```
   camlQuery1.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CauseID_x003a_Code'/><Value Type='Lookup'>"+strDamcode+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
   ```
2. If you want to search substring

   ```
   camlQuery1.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='CauseID_x003a_Code'/><Value Type='Lookup'>"+strDamcode+"</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");
   ```